# react i18next вставка переменных

Tags: reactjs, i18n

Есть код

```
import { translate, Interpolate } from 'react-i18next'
@translate('main')
export default class Comp extends Component {
  render () {
    let val = <span style={{ color: '#ff0000'}}>какой то текст</span>
    let val2 = <Interpolate i18nKey={ this.props.t('Другой текст') } value={val} />
      return {
          <div>{val2}</div>
      }
   }
}
```

Json файл

```
{
  'Другой текст': 'Другой текст {{ value }}'
}
```

Почему то не определяет переменную val. Может кто то сталкивался с таким??
Я так понимаю Trans в моем случае не подходит так как порядок текста может быть разным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так: `this.props.t('Другой текст', {value}) }`
если переменные не совпадают (value и val),то
`this.props.t('Другой текст', {value: val}) }`